# Program Freezes with NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

This may be pretty simple, but I have a WPF Application that has a button, a text area, and another button. If I click on Button 1, then the program creates a WaveOutEvent called player and plays the audio file. However, once it starts playing, I can't do anything else or even close the form (and can't type in the text area). Is it possible to play the file in the background? Any idea how I can fix this? Sorry, I'm new with C#. Here's some code:

```
  private void button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Program p = new Program(textBox1.Text); 
        p.Tempo = float.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        label2.Content = p.totalTime;
    }
  //assuming this has been called after initialization
  public void playAudio(string filename)
    {
        WaveStream rdr;

        if (filename.EndsWith(".aiff"))
        {
            rdr = new AiffFileReader(filename);
        }
        else if (filename.EndsWith(".mp3"))
        {
            rdr = new Mp3FileReader(filename);
        }
        else if (filename.EndsWith(".wav"))
        {
            rdr = new WaveFileReader(filename);
        }
        else
        {
            //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("File not supported.");
            rdr = new Mp3FileReader(filename);
        }

        volumeStream = new WaveChannel32(rdr);
        player = new WaveOutEvent();
        player.Init(volumeStream);
        format = volumeStream.WaveFormat;
        totalTime = volumeStream.TotalTime;
        inputProvider = new AdvancedBufferedWaveProvider(format);
        player.Init(inputProvider);
        player.Play(); //freezes application after starting to play
        //processAudio();
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does AdvancedBufferedWaveProvider do? Have you tried breaking in Visual Studio to see what is currently happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to play the audio.

Comment: WaveOutEvent already creates a background thread to play the audio on, so this will have no effect.

Comment: @MarkHeath Thanks for the input, I didn't know that. His problem just sounded very much like a UI thread blocking issue.